# How can i use a 3 V LED switch in an application that requires more

Tags: voltage, led, switches, dc

i have a circuit which requires something between 5 to 7 V (DC) from its input , and i would like to add an LED push button to it , however i only have this DC 3V LED momentary switch , and im  sure if there is a way to use it in the application in where i can still see it lighting !!

Is there like a parllel approach to where i could keep the voltage level to the input but the switch would still work and lights?

Comment: Please add more information. Do you have a part reference for the switch? What exactly do you want the switch to do?

Comment: i want to attach an ON/OFF switch to the device , and then attach an LED push button for me to use it , but as i said the device requires more voltage than the switch ,so is this possible ?                  this is the info from amazon for this switch  ,   Item Name : Push Button Switch;Poles : SPST;Action Type : Momentary Type
Switch Working Voltage : AC 250V 3A;Lamp Voltage : DC 3V;Lamp Color : Red(LED Lamp)

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by "button for me to use it" - I'm guessing you want the switch to connect or disconnect another circuit from the supply? Can you provide a link to the switch rather than amazon search terms? I can't locate the specific switch you want to use based on your description. The more specific information you can provide, the more we can help you!

Comment: yes exactly , so that the device will have an ON/OFF switch ( as a safety switch ) and once its ON the push button will be lighting and does it's job in connecting or disconnecting the circuit from the supply            ..... this is the name of this switch (2 Pcs 4 Terminals Red LED Lamp Momentary Push Button Switch DC 3V)

Comment: Well, there is no documentation for that switch on the amazon listing so we can only guess. The picture shows 4 pins on the switch, so we can probably assume that the LED light is pinned out completely independent of the switch. You can use the switch as you would any simple switch and derive your own circuit to light the LED according to the behavior you desire. Note that this is a momentary switch, not a toggle switch - the switch is only closed while you are holding the button down. From your limited information I'm not sure that this is what you want...

Comment: do you mean that i could only use it as a simple switch , because what i want it to be what it is a switch that lights , but the problem is that the LED of this switch only needs 3 V while the applciation where i want to this switch to be attached to required more voltage (7.4 V) as a max

Comment: You probably just need a resistor in series with the lamp but without more information it is difficult to tell.

Answer (score -1):

You could possible use a AMS1117 regulator to power the 3v LED (http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf). Just take the 5-7v output from your momentary switch as the input to the AMS1117 and the output of the AMS1117 to the LED. Common ground. You possibly wouldn't need the capacitors either as these are for smoothing the output for logic circuits. Small spikes shouldn't hurt your LED.

Comment: "You possibly wouldn't need the capacitors either as these are for smoothing the output for logic circuits." Wrong!!! Read the datasheet you posted: `The circuit design used in the AMS1117 series requires the use of
an output capacitor as part of the device frequency compensation.`
Without it the circuit might oscillate!